# How to calculate total time in oracle forms using date, hour and minute?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Help needed!

I am working on oracle forms 10g. I have created a form wherein I have 7 fields:

First 3 fields, namely `from_date` in date format, `from_hour` and `from_minute` in number format. 
Next 3 fields accept `to_date`, `to_hour` and `to_minute`.

`From_hour` and `to_hour` are accepted in 24HH format.

And the last field is, `total_time` which displays the result in **HH.MM** format by calculating the difference of from fields and to fields.

I can't get through this. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad design. You should have had only one item for both FROM and TO values, which would accept full datetime format. I'd suggest you to fix that.

In the meantime, convert those pairs into a true date format; use format mask which is appropriate to your situation. Here's an example:

```
declare
  l_from date := to_date(to_char(:from_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') ||' '||
                         lpad(:from_hour, 2, '0')          ||':'||
                         lpad(:from_minute, 2, '0'),
                         'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi');
  l_to   date := the same, just for TO values
  l_diff number;
begin
  l_diff := l_to - l_from;   -- it is number of DAYS
  ...
end;
```

As L_DIFF represents number of days between two dates (as that's what you get when subtracting them), you'd now have to convert it to hours (by multiplying it with 24, as there are 24 hours in a day), while for minutes you need to multiply with 60 (as there are 60 minutes in an hour).

Here's an example of how to do that: suppose that difference makes 0.3 days. It is then

```
SQL> with test as (select 0.3 days from dual)
  2  select trunc(days * 24)                      as hours,
  3         ((days * 24) - trunc(days * 24)) * 60 as minutes
  4  from test;

     HOURS    MINUTES
---------- ----------
         7         12
```

In Forms, that would be

```
declare 
  l_hours   number;
  l_minutes number;
  l_total   varchar2(10);
begin
  l_hours   := trunc(l_diff * 24);
  l_minutes := ((l_diff * 24) - trunc(l_diff * 24)) * 60;

  l_total   := lpad(to_char(l_hours), 2, '0') ||':'|| 
               lpad(to_char(l_minutes), 2, '0');
end;
```

Those two PL/SQL blocks would, of course, be just one (i.e. one DECLARE section, one BEGIN-END block).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But there's still one problem. When it comes to minutes, it is not accurate. Either it displays 25.59 or 25 and similar in other input cases too.

Comment: Well, you have the principle; feel free to improve it.

Comment: Just one question: 

what is happening in this query: `lpad(to_char(l_hours), 2, '0') ||':'|| lpad(to_char(l_minutes), 2, '0');`

What is the use of `2` and `0`?

Comment: LPAD will add '0' in front of L_HOURS value so that its length is max 2 characters. For example, if L_HOURS = 5, it'll make it 05. If L_HOURS = 13, then it won't do anything because it already is 2 characters long.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time.